# SQL - Hacer un CASE con LEFT JOIN

Tags: as400

Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TYVALOR, MVMVTO
FROM FVFPARTY AS FVFPARTY
LEFT JOINMVFDCTMON AS MVFDCTMON
ON FVFPARTY.TYVALOR = MVFDCTMON.MVCTRX
WHERE FVFPARTY.TYPAR='MVRCONSLD1' AND TYCON=2 AND  TYVAL =08100 AND TYHOM IN ('+','-')
```

me devuelve el siguiente registro:

```
TYVALOR             MVMMVTO    TYHOM
 01                    600        +
 02                    200        -
```

Lo que necesito es hacer un `case` que identifique que si viene una transacción con `tyvalor 1` y `tyhom +` realice la suma del campo `MVMMTO` Y si viene un `02` haga una resta de este campo `mvmmto`

Comment: Esta pregunta seria para db2, no?

Comment: @gbianchi, imagino que sí, y además de sql.

Comment: Es una consulta para as400

Comment: as400 es una arquitectura de un servidor.. en el estas corriendo una base de datos. que tipo de base de datos estas corriendo?

Comment: es una consulta tipo oracle